# Can you move a directory while data is being copied to it

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems, file-transfer, robocopy

I have a large set of data that is being copied to a directory on a server, around 2 tb. I would like to start moving this data(Ctrl-X) from server A to server B to save time and space on server A. Can I perform this move operation while a copy is active? I need the data to continue copying while the move is happening and hopefully move any new data that is present in the directory. I am using RoboCopy to perform the copy.

Comment: Robocopy can do that. Just use the monitoring function and have it continue to grab new files from the directory. make sure you do a multi-threaded copy and configure a reasonable retry interval. Files that are currently open (copying) will cause robocopy to retry for a period of time. Multithreaded copy will allow it to continue copying while it is waiting on another thread.

Comment: We need to know the parameters you are using for robocopy. @Appleoddity: The problem is that with the wrong parameters, the robocopy that is copying to the folder might decide to re-copy the moved-out files, creating a vicious loop.

Comment: @harrymc I am using a simple E parameter to copy all directories and sub-directories. I am hopeful that the move will transfer the data already copied over and that robo copy will not attempt to move that data again since it was already copied. If that makes sense. Assuming RoboCopy works in a linear fashion.

Comment: @Appleoddity This seems like a possible solution. Will the monitor function in conjunction with the multi-threaded copy free up space while doing the move to the other directory? Or will I bloat up two servers instead of streaming that data?

Comment: Also, its important to note that this transfer has taken weeks (Slow server A). So this move is risky, I do not want to corrupt any data or have to start over.

Comment: There is the risk of copying partially-copied files, if robocopy does not lock the target file against read while doing the copy, and even so the second robocopy might fail when trying to delete that partially-copied file. I suggest experimenting, but on another computer.